# How do I use Loggly and Django to log a unique ID per session?

Tags: python, django, logging, loggly

I have my Django logging setup like this (below). The filter for request ID comes from here, https://github.com/dabapps/django-log-request-id. I set up Loggly following the tutorial here: https://www.loggly.com/docs/python-http/. However, it appears their provided config file overrides the standard formatter, meaning it does not include request_id.

Is there a way I can use both request_id and Loggly? Basically, I would like Loggly to always log a request_id which is unique and comes from the plugin log_request_id.filters.RequestIDFilter.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'request_id': {
            '()': 'log_request_id.filters.RequestIDFilter'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
        'json': {
            'format': '{ "loggerName":"%(name)s", "timestamp":"%(asctime)s", "fileName":"%(filename)s", "logRecordCreationTime":"%(created)f", "functionName":"%(funcName)s", "levelNo":"%(levelno)s", "lineNo":"%(lineno)d", "time":"%(msecs)d", "levelName":"%(levelname)s", "message":"%(message)s"}',
        },
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] [%(request_id)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['request_id'],
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
        },
        'loggly': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'loggly.handlers.HTTPSHandler',
            'filters': ['request_id'],
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'url': 'https://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/TOKEN/tag/python',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        },
        'root': {
            'handlers': ['loggly', ],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        }
    }
}
```